# C# Async Sockets - Thread Logic

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous

How does the thread creation logic behind Socket.BeginSend, Socket.BeginReceive, Socket.BeginAccept, etc. works?

Is it going to create a new thread for each client that connects to my server to handle the code, or is it only going to create one thread for each function(accept, receive, send...) no mattering how many clients there are connected to the server? This way only executing the client 2 accept code once the client 1 accept code is completed and so on.

This is the code I made and I am trying to understand the logic behind it better:

```
public class SocketServer
{
    Socket _serverSocket;
    List<Socket> _clientSocket = new List<Socket>();
    byte[] _globalBuffer = new byte[1024];

    public SocketServer()
    {
        _serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    }

    public void Bind(int Port)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Setting up server...");
        _serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, Port));
    }

    public void Listen(int BackLog)
    {
        _serverSocket.Listen(BackLog);
    }

    public void Accept()
    {
        _serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);
    }

    private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        Socket socket = _serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
        _clientSocket.Add(socket);
        Console.WriteLine("Client Connected");
        socket.BeginReceive(_globalBuffer, 0, _globalBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, socket);
        Accept();
    }

    private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        Socket socket = AR.AsyncState as Socket;
        int bufferSize = socket.EndReceive(AR);

        string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_globalBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
        Console.WriteLine("Text Received: {0}", text);

        string response = string.Empty;

        if (text.ToLower() != "get time")
            response = $"\"{text}\" is a Invalid Request";
        else
            response = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();

        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response);
        socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, SendCallback, socket);

        socket.BeginReceive(_globalBuffer, 0, _globalBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, socket);
    }

    private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        (AR.AsyncState as Socket).EndSend(AR);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These kinds of asynchronous methods use threads from the thread pool to invoke your callback, once the underlying event, whatever it may be, occurs. In your case, the underlying event might be a connection was established, or you received some data.

When you set a socket to 'accept', no thread needs to exist. The old synchronous way of doing things was to have one thread that just blocks on `socket.Accept()` until a connection comes in, but the point of these `Begin..()` methods is to do away with that.

Here's a trick, one that .Net uses and one that you use: You can register any WaitHandle object (a lock such as Semaphore, SemaphoreSlim, Mutex, etc) and a callback method with the thread pool, such that when the WaitHandle becomes set, the thread pool will pick a thread, run your callback, and return the thread to the thread pool.  See [`ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9f75h7a(v=vs.110).aspx).

Turns out many of these `Begin..()` methods basically do the same thing. `BeginAccept()` uses a WaitHandle to know when a socket has received a connection - it registers the WaitHandle with the ThreadPool and then calls your callback on a ThreadPool thread when a connection occurs.

Every time you call `Begin...()` and provide a callback, you should assume that your callback method could be invoked on a new thread, simultaneously with every other `Begin...()` call you've ever made that's still outstanding.

Call `BeginReceive()` 50 times on 50 different sockets? You should assume 50 threads could try to invoke your callback method at the same time. Call a mix of 50 `BeginReceive()` and `BeginAccept()` methods? 50 threads.

In reality, how many simultaneous invocations of your callbacks occur will be limited by the policy set in the ThreadPool, eg, how fast it may make new threads, how many threads it keeps live ready to go, etc.

With that, you should understand that calling `BeginReceive()` on 50 different sockets, but passing in the same buffer - `_globalBuffer` - means that 50 sockets are going to write to that same buffer and just make a mess of it, resulting in arbitrary/corrupted data.

Instead, you should use a unique buffer per simultaneous `BeginReceive()` call. What I would recommend doing is creating a new class to store the context of a single connection - the socket for the connection, the buffer to use for reading, its state, etc. Every new connection gets a new context instance.

...

FYI, the modern way of performing asynchronous programming in C# is to use the `async/await` keywords and matching `async` methods from the API. That design is much more complicated and much more deeply integrated with the execution environment than these `Begin...()` methods, and the answers to questions like "when do my callbacks get called", "what thread(s) are my callbacks called on", and "how many callbacks might run simultaneously" depend entirely on the execution environment of your program consequent to the async/await design in C# / .Net.

Comment: I was wide aware of the problem with the _globalBuffer, I thought it would happen because of multiple concurrents trying to access the same variable. I decided that I needed to know how the threads would be created before trying to find a solution for it. I was thinking what would be cheaper to do, put a unique buffer on each function, or put a lock/await on the global buffer? I only got lost at your recommendation at the end, I am new to programing, could you try to explain it in different ways if possible? Thank you very much for your explanation btw.

Comment: Theres no part of this design that allows you to use a lock on globalBuffer to prevent multiple threads from writing to it simultaneously - the buffer is written to by code you do not control, that executes at a time you do not control. You call BeginReceive and some time later the OS writes to your buffer and informs you. Assuming that one socket will only ever have one BeginReceive call outstanding at a time, then you could use one buffer per socket. If you really want your whole program to have only one buffer, then you must make sure that you only have one BeginReceive pending, period.

Comment: Also, if you're new to programming, ignore the async/await feature in c# for now.

Comment: I think the most important question... When will the Socket API support `async/await` ? @antiduh

Comment: I don't normally use C#, so when I looked at this BeginSend and BeginReceive stuff, I am unsure if I am reading it right.  It seems from the docs that the thread that will call back after BeginSend isn't the same thread as the one that does BeginReceive for the SAME socket.    So that means any application data structures that you want to access between your send and receive calls aren't protected for you, and you still need to use some sort of locks to protect your application data between send and receive?